# Xcode ignoring my static library because it was build with armv6 and my target device is armv7 based

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4 Final - “armv6 armv7” issue while linking with armv6 libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316495/xcode-4-final-armv6-armv7-issue-while-linking-with-armv6-libs)

I have a problem since upgrading to Xcode 3.2.6 (why is it never simple -.- )

I had working project that failed to link after I updated Xcode.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/bd/Documents/IR/liblibmms.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)

I gather this means that Xcode is not happy because the library was built for armv6 but my target is an armv7 based phone so it will no longer accept it.

Can I force the compiler to accept it like it used to  before i updated? Anybody able to advise me how to make the compiler stop ignoring the file?

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: see [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316495/xcode-4-final-armv6-armv7-issue-while-linking-with-armv6-libs)...

Comment: The topic is the same, but the question was not. "Can I force the compiler to accept it like it used to before i updated? Anybody able to advise me how to make the compiler stop ignoring the file?" I am asking something specific that was not addressed or asked in that thread. "how to make the compiler stop ignoring the file"