# libobjc.A.dylib compile error on iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having a compiling error in iOS Simulator 4.3 I can't actually figure it out, The error I get is:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_retain
  Referenced from: /Users/ben/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/75915A97-7C3D-489A-B7B0-7B6895A4B584/AppName.app/AppName
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_retain
  Referenced from: /Users/ben/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/75915A97-7C3D-489A-B7B0-7B6895A4B584/AppName.app/AppName
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Note:
The library being referenced (libobjc.A.dylib) is actually in the 'Expected Place'
The code works fine on an iOS5 device, and in iOS5 Simulator.

Comment: Are you using ARC in this project?  Could your question be a [duplicate of this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423489/objective-c-arc-errors-automatic-release-problems)

Comment: not using ARC, the project is too complicated to turn it on.

Comment: This symbol is not in the 4.3 lib, I wonder who's requesting this. Go to both dirs and do `nm libobjc.A.dylib | grep retain`, with 4.3 you'll see only one symbol _SEL_retain. Tried to clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: I have the exact same problem after I upgraded to XCode 5.4 and IOS 6.0. The accepted answer does not work for me. Does anybody has other ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add `-fobjc-arc` in Build Settings => Other Linker Flags (**OTHER_LDFLAGS**) for the different configurations

Comment: doesn't this force enable arc for the entire project? isn't the point to not enable arc?

Comment: No, it doesn't doesn't force it for the whole project.

Comment: You use it as a **linker** flag, not a **compiler** flag, so it doesn't affect ARC at compilation time, only at link time.

Comment: this worked, but if the project has only few files that need this flag and when we can add flag for each file separately, why do we need to add this on project level?

Answer (score 1):

> This problem occurs if you use a library that uses ARC and want to
>   build/run on older iOS 4 devices.

In Build Settings => Other Linker Flags

- Add `-fobjc-arc`
- If yet not solved, then add `-weak_library /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib`