# iOS SqlCipher Sqlite Simulator Ok, deploy on device error

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios-simulator, sqlcipher

In my iOS app, I'm using SqlCipher. 
When I run my project using the Simulator - everything works good (Xcode 4.5, iOS simulator 5.1).

But when I try to deploy my project on my iPhone 4 (iOS 5.1.1) I have 20 errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
...

"_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
...
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
....

I tried to include libsqlite3.dylib in Link Binary With Libraries, but i still have some errors (and in SQLcipher doc they precise to delete libsqlite3.dylib):

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_sqlite3_key", referenced from:

I really don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: I just turned the Build active architecture only to Yes in the Project -> Build Setting -> Architectures tab.     Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316495/xcode-4-final-armv6-armv7-issue-while-linking-with-armv6-libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `armv7s` and instead target `armv7`, like this:

[image: buildsettings]

However, according to [this](http://sqlcipher.net/blog/2012/9/27/sqlcipher-now-supports-iphone-5-xcode-45-and-armv7s.html), SQLCipher now supports `armv7s`, were you using an older version?